# Paw File behaves differently when an Environment Variable in multipart form-data

Tags: multipartform-data, environment, paw-app

I'm trying to use Environments in Paw to help with testing a web API that uses a multipart/form-data submission of an image file.  Paw will do this fine if I have a Body part name with a Value of the "File" type and drag my image file in.
[file in multipart form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYSwV.png)
This produces a request part like:

```
--Emm5HQuI6PlP2Jo1k3KW284fY8yeluRO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="persfront"; filename="sample_front.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿá ExifMM*i&;...
```

But when I try to abstract that file out of the normal Multipart Body window and into an Environment variable and then use that, it still puts the file contents in the request, but leaves the file information out of the part header.
This:
[environment variables for file in form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQXCF.png)
produces this request:

```
--2gEAMPgSTNfB0dsLImFDHYMRLjqag7Hu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="persfront"

ÿØÿá ExifMM*i&;...
```

The lack of file header, normally supplied in there, causes my request to fail.

It's as if the environment variable is being evaluated prior to it being used and so the multipart form is just seeing a bunch of binary instead of a file.  Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

Is there any other way to use the utility of the Environments in this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably very late for an answer, but yes, Paw has a special case where if the content of a multipart request is a file, it will include the filename in the multpart headers. Though, if you abstract the file in an environment variable, this special case isn't honoured anymore...

Comment: Thanks, Micha.  You're letting me know I'm not using it incorrectly then.  It'd be a good feature to add as, to me, the functionality seems implied through the excellent Environments functionality.  My intended use case is maintaining sanity tests in the environments as doing whatever... it's a quick way to substitute in data and a little more elegant than the alternative of putting multiple, identical Part Names and selectively shutting some off.  Thats really what the Environments seems aimed at.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I should have been more clear in my answer that it is the current behavior of Paw, and it certainly is not the ideal one. Thanks for reminding me with this comment: I'll create a ticket so I make sure this get fixed in one of the next releases. For now, I'm afraid I don't have a workaround, but once fixed you'll be able to set files in Env Variables. Thanks!

Comment: I know that was 4 years ago, but this is solved somehow @MichaMazaheri?

Comment: This has now been solved. The file's metadata (filename, MIME type) is now extracted even if the file is defined through an environment variable. Here's a screenshot that shows this: https://share.getcloudapp.com/WnuExmA7